# Insert same auto increment value to another column of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'demo' with 3 columns. id,name and pixel. In this id is primary with auto-increment. i need to insert id auto increment value to pixel column during in insertion

Comment: so you want `pixel` to equal `id`?

Comment: yes..............

Comment: you can do this in a trigger

Comment: You might be able to do this with a generated column if your version of mysql supports it.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

Comment: Why would you create one more column in a table having exact same value as the other. Why not use the already existing column in the first place ? it seems to be a bad design, unless there is some interesting rationale behind this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious question is, if `pixel` always equals `id` , why do you need it at all? If you're using the value from `id` as an initial default value, why not have it default to `NULL`?

That being said, you do have a couple of options:

1. As @PSalmon noted, you can use a generated column if your version supports it:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE demo
   (
       `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `name` VARCHAR(255),
       pixel AS (`id`)
   )
   ```
2. As @WhatsThePoint noted, you can use a [trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html). On an insert, update `pixel` to match `id`.

Again though, there really isn't a need to have a separate attribute with the same value as `id`. If you really need it, you can create a view with a `pixel` column matching your `id`.