# Inserting identity column value as param to other column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, insert, identity

I have a table named tab_stores, it's structure is shown below

```
CREATE TABLE tab_stores
(
    id_num INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    sName VARCHAR(20),
    mySKey VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Now, when I insert the values in this table using the query below, it inserts values and increments the `id_num` by +1 which is working fine.

```
INSERT tab_stores (sName, mySKey)
VALUES ('Store', 'Store');
```

The data inserted is

```
1,Store,Store
```

I want to modify it a bit so that when I insert the row, the auto incremented column value should be post fixed and added in `mySKey` column, so the result should be

```
1,Store,Store1
```

I have tried using the query below, but it does not work - and I get

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server 49706b09f367, Line 7
> Invalid column name 'id_num'

```
INSERT tab_stores (sName, mySKey)
VALUES ('Store', 'Store' + id_num);
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Please remove `MySQL` from the tag

Comment: Sure, I have removed it

Comment: It can't be done like that. One way is to do this inside a trigger

Comment: Seems like a computed column would be a simple solution.

Answer (score 5):

If this rule always applies - then you have two options:

1. Create a **view** on top of your table that handles this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tab_stores
(
    id_num INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    sName VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE VIEW dbo.view_Stores
AS
    SELECT
        id_num, sName,
        sName + CAST(id_num AS VARCHAR(10)) AS mySKey
    FROM
        dbo.tab_stores;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.view_Stores;
```

2. You could also create a **computed** column in your base table (instead of creating a separate column and filling it):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tab_stores
(
    id_num INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    sName VARCHAR(20),
    mySKey AS sName + CAST(id_num AS VARCHAR(10)) PERSISTED
);

INSERT INTO dbo.tab_stores (sName) 
VALUES ('Store'), ('StoreABC');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.view_Stores;

1,'Store','Store1'
2,'StoreABC','StoreABC2'
```

Answer (score -1):

Get max id_num value from `tab_scores` and concatenate with "Store" text.
But when table has now rows, max function prints `NULL` so use isnull function to change 1.

```
INSERT tab_stores (sName, mySKey)
VALUES ('Store', 'Store' + convert(varchar,(select isnull(max(id_num) + 1, 1) from tab_stores)));
```

Answer (score -2):

you can check the below links for getting some idea.

[Insert same auto increment value to another column of same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608292/insert-same-auto-increment-value-to-another-column-of-same-table)
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/use-generated-identity-for-another-column-within-the-same-insert

Thanks.